# Overlay grid on responsive image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a standard image (that is responsive because of bootstap) and would like to overlay a standard grid 5% x 5% on top of it.

I need to pick points on the images and need the grid to be visible as well as the image.

I upload the image via form and it show up in a form location on the html. I would like to know how to add additional css on top it - to get the grid on top it.

See the image below for a sample (I only put 8 grid - but I would like 5% spacing or 10% spacing both x and y).

[image]

Comment: I don't know where to start - but here is a code pen. the grid needs to appear on top of the dummy image. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyMVdq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)s on pseudo-elements of the div, one on `::before` and one on `::after`, we can create two simple lines which are then repeated every nth-percent with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). The `::after` pseudo-element is rotated 90deg to create the horizontal lines. It looks like this:

```css
.grid::before,
.grid::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 10%;
}

.grid::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

The two gradients create two intersecting lines which are a percentage size long, like this:

[image: The grid lines]

These lines are repeated with the default [`background-repeat: repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat), which creates a grid, like this:

[image: The grid]

When the `::before` and [`::after` pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) are placed over the image we get this:

[image: Result]

You can create a fixed grid size, using a fixed pixel `background-size`:

```
.fixed::before,
.fixed::after {
  background-size: 23px;
}
```

### Example

**Note** how the entire grid is given an outline using `box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 2px #000;` on `::before`.

```css
*,
*::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid img {
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.grid::before,
.grid::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size: 10%;
}

.grid::before {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.56);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 2px #000;
}

.grid::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.fixed::before,
.fixed::after {
  background-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc" width="300" height="300" />
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ccc" width="200" height="200" />
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc" width="100" height="100" />
</div>

<div class="grid fixed">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x500/ccc" width="500" height="500" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting and nice. any change of limiting this to the img only ? if I use this class - it put a grid on ALL the div's. how can I limit to images only. I think the bootstarp class is "img-responsive" - but this is awesome direction - thanks

Comment: @hypermails - Easy :) the image itself needs to be wrapped in a div, so just target the div with a class. Example: `<div class="grid"><img /></div>` and place the CSS properties on `.grid` instead of div.

Comment: Is it expected result I get only vertical lines when running the example (both in the Run code snippet and when going to the link provided in the "Here is an example for you" comment? (Running on Chrome 74.0.3729.169, Win10 x64).

Comment: @Suma Thanks for asking me :) looks like things have changed since 2015. I have fixed the CSS in my answer. The horizontal lines are now provided by a second pseudo-element which is rotated 90deg. I also added a fixed size grid example which could come in handy for some use cases.