# How to apply SVG effects to an image or div container?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

It's the first time I'm going to use SVG graphics and I'm a bit confused… I've researched extensively but I cannot seem to find an answer to what I'm trying to do.

I want to give an image the following appearance, given the source image is a color image.

[image: color image with gradient map and pattern overlay]

The main reason behind this effect is to overcome bad quality images (both in terms of aesthetics and resolution) my clients might upload to their websites.

In Photoshop this is a Gradient Map and a transparent grid in Mode Multiply.

I've managed to apply a filter for the grayscale and "gradient map" but I cannot add the grid/pattern.

This is my code so far:

SVG file gradient-map.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <filter id="duotone_filter">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
         values="1 0 0 0 0
                 1 0 0 0 0
                 1 0 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 1 0" >
      </feColorMatrix>
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone">
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0039525691 0.5764705882"></feFuncR>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.8431372549"></feFuncG>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.9803921569"></feFuncB>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
     </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>        
</svg>
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="link/to/file" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
   filter: url('../images/gradient-map.svg#duotone_filter');
}
```

And the SVG file for the pattern/fill

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="6px" height="6px" viewBox="0 0 6 6">
   <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="2" />
</svg>
```

Is this the way things should be done? How should I proceed to achieve this effect?

If you could also link me to useful resources I would much appreciate. I haven't found any recent guides or articles.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get a transparent grid from somewhere, like https://www.transparenttextures.com/ and load that image along with your current image?

Comment: I could, but that's not what I'm looking for…

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. Here's a demo I put together (and on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tombarr/pen/jZVwwg)). And the output:

[image]

There's a helpful question to [Overlay grid on responsive image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556463/overlay-grid-on-responsive-image), but I opted for simply overlaying and scaling a large transparent PNG. You'll likely end up with better results if you use a small, repeating grid section. Of course you'll have to choose what color, size, etc. to make the grid overlay.

As a side note, you cannot use the `:after` or `:before` pseudo-elements with `img` elements, so you need to wrap them in a container. You could also accomplish this with an additional element, like:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="..." />
    <div class="grid-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

But I prefer pseudo-elements so I don't have to repeat `<div class="grid-overlay"></div>` every time I want the grid overlay.

```css
img {
  filter: url(#duotone_filter)
}

.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 375px;
}

.img-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/grid-png-31.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"><img src="http://kb4images.com/images/random-image/37670495-random-image.jpg" /></div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <filter id="duotone_filter">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
         values="1 0 0 0 0
                 1 0 0 0 0
                 1 0 0 0 0
                 0 0 0 1 0" >
      </feColorMatrix>
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone">
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0039525691 0.5764705882"></feFuncR>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.8431372549"></feFuncG>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.9803921569"></feFuncB>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
     </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>        
</svg>
```

Also an example using [**only SVGs** (symbols)](https://codepen.io/Tombarr/pen/yvVzGw):

[image: SVG symbol grid overlay]

One [final example](https://codepen.io/Tombarr/pen/gvLXeB) that also works in Firefox and uses two SVG filters. The key to this example is that it uses another filter to create a composite image. I took another SVG from the web but you could use an inline SVG and reference it by ID as well.

```
<filter id="overlay">
    <feImage result="sourceTwo" xlink:href="http://www.vectorstash.com/vectors/vectorstash-grid.svg" width="500" height="375" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="sourceTwo" operator="out" x="0" y="0" />
  </filter>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I could use a PNG transparent grid, but I'm looking for a SVG only solution, performance-wise.

Comment: @DiogoBento Here's another Codepen using SVG symbols: https://codepen.io/Tombarr/pen/yvVzGw. I would actually refactor the grid to an external SVG and include is as a background image (as mentioned above), but this system works too. Now the grid is programatic in that you can control color, spacing, etc.

Comment: Not working in Firefox, is it? But thanks anyway, it's much closer to what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: @DiogoBento I guess not, sorry I tested in Chrome. That is strange, my guess is Firefox needs an explicit viewBox attribute or something along those lines. It should actually be able to combine these two options by applying one filter mask to the image and one to its container (for overlaying the grid). See https://www.sitepoint.com/design-tricks-with-svg-filters-a-masked-blur-effect/

Answer (score 2):

A handy way to do this is to combine the grid overlay with the filter by putting inline SVG for the grid into an feImage primitive.

(I also changed your greyscale matrix because it was only using the red channel as source which is going to create weird results on blue/green heavy photos.)

```css
.filterclass {
    filter: url(#duotone_filter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <filter id="duotone_filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage width="6" height="6" xlink:href= "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%226px%22%20height%3D%226px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%206%206%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%226%22%20height%3D%226%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22grey%22/%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E"/>
      <feTile result="overlay"/>


      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" result="grayscale"
         values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                 .33 .33 .33 0 0
                 .33 .33 .33 0 0
                 0 0 0 1 0" />

      <feComponentTransfer result="duotone">
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0039525691 0.5764705882"></feFuncR>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.8431372549"></feFuncG>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.0123456790 0.9803921569"></feFuncB>
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
     </feComponentTransfer>
    <feBlend mode="multiply" in="overlay"/>
  </filter>        
</svg>

<div >
<img class="filterclass" src="http://kb4images.com/images/random-image/37670495-random-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

The source SVG for the inlined data uri is

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="6px" height="6px" viewBox="0 0 6 6">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="6" height="6" fill="none" stroke="grey"/>
</svg>
```

If you want to tweak it - I use this converter for svg+xml - which is pretty useful https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/JDqvs